# Is it considered "marit ayin" if boys and girls stroll together on Shabbat?

Tags: halacha, chinuch-education, marit-ayin

I have heard of a number of yeshivot that have a strict rule regarding boys and girls being with each other. Their rule is "simple" - outside of your own family members, it should be never for any reason.

Let's say Reuven's friend, Benzi (who are in the same class) has a sister, Talia. The three of them walk together on the street on Shabbat to visit their friends, Habakuk & Reut. Is this activity "marit ayin"? Keep in mind, that there is no prohibition, per se, even according to the yeshiva's rules about Benzi talking to Talia, as they are siblings. But, people don't know Talia, who don't know the family. Also, it IS against the yeshiva rules for Reuven to be with Talia.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's Maaras Ayin [Brachos 43b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=43b&format=text)

> ואל יספר עם אשה בשוק אמר רב חסדא ואפילו היא אשתו תניא נמי הכא אפילו היא אשתו ואפילו היא בתו ואפילו היא אחותו לפי שאין הכל בקיאין בקרובותיו
>
> And one shouldn't talk to strangers in the marketplace.
>
> Rav Chisda said that the law applies even with his wife, and a Braisa said that [this law applies] even with his wife, daughter or sister since not everyone is fluent in his relatives.

Comment: Do we pasken like that? – Not if common custom is to be taken as an indication of halacha. But I am not sure about that.

Comment: Where does the gemara say that's it's an issue of מראית עין?

Comment: @Ephraim its מראית עין, what else would it be?